# Algoritmo para convertir un número binario a un numero entero

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Hice un algoritmo para convertir un número binario a un número entero, la cuestión es que hice bastantes lineas de código, mi solución a ese problema es esta:

```
const binaryArrayToNumber = arr => {
 let contador = 1;
 let bin;
 let binArr = [];
 for(let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      contador = contador * 2;
      bin = contador / 2;
      if(arr[i] === 1){
           binArr.push(bin);
      }
 }
 for(let i = 0; i < binArr.length; i ++){
      if(binArr[i] !== 0){
           binArr = binArr.reduce((valorAntetior, valorActual) => valorAntetior + valorActual);
           return binArr;     
      } else {
           return 0;
      }
 }
};
```

Pero al ver otras soluciones descubrí esta solución:

```
const binaryArrayToNumber = arr => {
 return parseInt(arr.join(""),2);
};
```

Alguien me podría explicar la última solución? no logro entender cuál es la función de ese 2, gracias.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por lo que veo lo que esta pasando es que, primero esta escrito en ECMAScript 6 y luego en la [documentación de mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) indica que:

> La función `parseInt` comprueba el primer argumento, una cadena, e intenta devolver un entero de la base especificada. Por ejemplo, una base de 10 indica una conversión a número decimal, 8 octal, 16 hexadecimal, y así sucesivamente. Para bases superiores a 10, las letras del alfabeto indican numerales mayores que 9. Por ejemplo, para números hexadecimales (base 16), se utiliza de la A hasta la F.

Cuando corres `arr.join("char")` el array se va a convertir en cadena separando los valores con el carácter o caracteres especificados, en este caso `""` o nada, por lo que el array va a quedar de la siguiente manera (como ejemplo):

```
var arr = [1,0]
arr = arr.join("") => "10"
```

Luego parseInt evalúa si el valor es valido para la representación binaria del mismo e intenta convertirlo a entero.

**Entonces como ejemplo:**

```
var arr = [1,0,1,1,1];
arr = arr.join("");
var entero = parseInt(arr, 2) => 23
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda, ¡Un saludo!.

Answer (score 2):

La función parseInt comprueba el primer argumento, una cadena, e intenta devolver un entero de la base especificada. Por ejemplo, una base de 10 indica una conversión a número decimal, 8 octal, 16 hexadecimal, y así sucesivamente. Para bases superiores a 10, las letras del alfabeto indican numerales mayores que 9. Por ejemplo, para números hexadecimales (base 16), se utiliza de la A hasta la F.

Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt